# streaming video from iphone to server programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller

I need to implement iphone video streaming to server. I've googled a lot but I found only receiving video streams from server. It is made using UIWebView or MPMoviewPlayer.
But how can I stream my captured media to server in realtime?
How can it be done?

Comment: I guess that you just need to upload the file to the server, the server will have to handle the streaming i.e. playing the file as the server receives it. You just have to make sure that the upload starts sending the data from the start of the file (which I believe is the standard)

Comment: I must upload a video while capturing it in realtime. So when the video is capturing on the device. device uploads it to server and server will stream it. It must be done in real time. So the delay from capturing video on the device and server's stream output of this video must be minimum. about 2-5 seconds would be nice

Comment: @user1385666: Do you get any solution. I am also developing similar app. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check out this Apple sample code. this is using a AVFoundation.

[StitchedStreamPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/StitchedStreamPlayer/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: As I understand StichedStreamPlayer breaks media into pieces with start time and end time

Comment: upload the video to your server, please test. When I was tested in the past was good for me.

Comment: any code sample for uploading the video to server, please!